# SQL query - "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Decimal found" using the value

Tags: sql-server, database, python-2.7, robotframework

I have connected to my DB successfully; I'm trying to run an sql query and get the 1st value of table into my result to use it further in my test steps. Now, I'm getting "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Decimal found" error. Please suggest valuable ideas on how to get a single value from the DB table and put it in the screen field to proceed with test case execution.

Please note, all are integer type values in my sql query result but still I don't know why the system says decimal found.

Below is my code:

> ```
> Connect to Database   pymssql  DBNAME  UNAME  PWD  PORTNO 
> ${QueryResult}= Query SelectQuery                             
> Log  ${QueryResult[0]}              
> Inputtext  id  ${QueryResult[0]}
> ```

The output of my log keyword is `(Decimal('2'),)` which is supposed to be a table value of 2.

After this the system tries to input  `(Decimal('2'),)` into the field and above said error is thrown.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying with, and the exact error message.

Comment: Connect to Database   pymssql  DBNAME  UNAME  PWD  PORTNO <br/> ${QueryResult}= Query SelectQuery  <br/>                                                             
Log  ${QueryResult[0]}  <br/>   Inputtext  id  ${QueryResult[0]}

Comment: Add it in the question's body, with proper formatting. Where does it fail - if at `Input text`, what's the output of the `Log` keyword?

Comment: Sorry @Todor im a newbie here. Now i posted with right formatting in questions body with some modifications. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues you've hit; the first one is - the result set from an sql query is a list of tuples, e.g. a two-dimensional structure.
Each list member (a tuple) is a row of the response; each tuple member is a column in that row. You can see that when you run the `Log`:

```
Log  ${QueryResult[0]}
# the output is
#  (Decimal('2'),)
# e.g. "a single row, that has only one column" - just one tuple member
```

, which is the whole row. So to get the actual value, if it's in the 1st column, you have to specify it:

```
${value}=    Set Variable    ${QueryResult[0][0]}
# if you run Log on it, the output most probably looks like this:
#   Decimal('2')
```

So now you have the value, but you're at the second issue - its datatype is the complex Decimal type. In general, that shouldn't be a problem - RF (actually python) should be able to cast it automatically, but if the error persists/or to be extra sure, you can convert it to string before using it in the `Input Text`:

```
${value}=    Convert To String    ${value}    # now it's no longer Decimal, but plain str type
Input Text   id    ${value}
```

*btw, unrelated - I don't think the locator "id" given to the `Input Text` keyword is a correct one, just copied what you've used in the sample.*

Comment: Hi @Todor , Thank you very much for highlighting the mistakes i have done. Now it is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DatabaseLibrary than result of `Query` keyword is tuple of tuples [1](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.0.1/DatabaseLibrary.html#Query). To access first value in first row you could do the following:

```
${result}    Query    ${query_string}
${first}    Set Variable    ${result[0][0]}
```

Edit: You are getting `Decimal('2')` because column in database has decimal datatype. In you query you could convert it to float using `CAST(<column_name> as FLOAT)`, but note, that you could lose precision.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JaPyR's. But i'm still getting the same error.